# react fragment got unexpected token error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm using semantic ui react, and I have this jsx

```
{role !== 'member' && (
  <>
    <Dropdown.Item>
      menu 1
    </Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item>
      menu 2
    </Dropdown.Item>
  </>
)}
```

I'm on "react": "^16.6.0", so fragment should work, but it didn't, any clue?

Comment: It's actually JSX syntax support, Are you using webpack as a build tool ?

Comment: you need Babel v7.0.0-beta.31 and above for react fragment shorthand support, ref  : https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html#support-for-fragment-syntax

Comment: I'm using create-react-app, tried `npm update @babel/core @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx
` and `npm update @babel/core @babel/preset-react
` still doesn't work

Comment: If you can't work out why the shorthand syntax isn't working, as a workaround, you could `import { Fragment } from 'react';` and then use `<Fragment>...</Fragment>`. (or just use `<React.Fragment>...</React.Fragment>`)

Comment: @JoelCox yeah create-react-app v2 only can use shorthand, too bad.